# Why do build systems like CMake generate recursive makefiles instead of one big makefile?

Tags: makefile, cmake, build-system

It always puzzled me why a build tool like Ninja was created when a big Makefile that encompasses the entire project (or at least most of it) accomplishes about the same. Empty builds are mostly a problem with recursive Makefiles, not with a single big one. So, I wonder if there is a reason why no Makefile-producing buildsystem like CMake or qmake produces a single big one. I do get it that manually writing one big Makefile can be difficult and a hassle to maintain, but an autogenerated one? Are there some fundamental limitations inside Make that pose a limit on how big/complex a Makefile can be? Or is there another gain in the Ninja approach beyond speed & empty builds?

Comment: Of course, this begs a reference to [*Recursive Make Considered Harmful*](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf), though that's by no means the last word on the subject.

Comment: However, this question is extremely broad and does seem to call for speculation, as I can't imagine that there's anyone who could speak authoritatively for *all* Makefile-producing build systems.

Comment: That is true. However, I suppose there are a few very common reasons for this design choice. The only one I can think of myself is that maybe recursive makefile generation is easier to implement.